# Best way to Display an error message - Call Apex Class methods from custom button or link

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button

I am trying to avoid to create a js button, then I have applied the following pattern to have a custom button.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325250&type=1&mode=1

My aim now is to add a validation error if it is met a criteria dont allow the user continue with the button action,
I have tried `<apex:pageMessage/>` with `ApexPages.severity.Error` but I have been not able to get it.

Can you recommend me it other approach?

Thanks

What it should be the best way to achieve?

Comment: Can you give us more background about the use case?  I'm not sure what a custom button has to do with validation checks on a VF page

Comment: @BrianMiller . Basically  the button should send an email from Quote object to a specific mailist. I am able to  send it without problems.  But I have got a new request that the email can only be sent if the account (parent object of the Quote) meet a certain criteria. In case the criteria is not meet i should display an alert or error message.  Temporally I have done a JS button with alert, but my aim is to follow  the patter VF + appex class + custom button. Thank you